# Permissions not saved

Tags: permissions

when trying to save permissions for user roles CiviCRM permissions(CiviCRM > Administer > Users and Permissions > Permissions (Access Control) > Wordpress Access Control), the permission are not saved and appears to be unchecked everytime I save them.

Wordpress
CiviCRM 5.67.1
PHP 8.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen a similar problem when the application has too many roles resulting in a huge permission matrix.

Check if there is a PHP warning or error for max_input_vars in the PHP log. If yes, [try increasing the size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602535/how-to-change-max-input-vars).